# AndroidJUnit4 not startable from IntelliJ

Tags: android, junit4

I have put a AndroidJUnit4 test into the

> 'app\src\androidTest\java\myPackage'

Folder and wanted to start the test from IntelliJ. Obviuosly there is something wrong, because I am missing the green start Icon on the left.

[image]

My dependencies:
testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'

Anyone has a hint, whats wrong?